# Generic gamepad with UWP on IoT devices

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-iot-core, gamepad

I am working on a program that needs to run on a Raspberry pi 3 running IoT and a windows-10 desktop. I want to use gamepad both connected through usb and bluetooth. The "windows.gaming.input.gamepad" api that Microsoft made only supports Xbox 360 and Xbox one controllers.

Is there a api that I can use to get the values from a gamepad?

Comment: No the API doesn't only support Xbox controllers, many other compatible with the api.

Comment: The "windows.gaming.input.gamepad" API doesn't support other controllers. It is stated on the API reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Microsoft has another API that is in pre-release. This API will work with all kinds of joysticks. The API is [windows.gaming.input.rawgamecontroller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.gaming.input.rawgamecontroller)